# 'NSObjectInaccessibleException' - CoreData sharing with TodayViewExtension

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I've kinda implemented a today view extension with CoreData sharing in my app, I have multiple problems (like only one object showing when I have three) and a big one, "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSObjectInaccessibleException', reason: 'CoreData could not fulfill a fault for '0xd0000000001c0004". Now, this only happens when I have the application open in the background, which leads me to believe that my app is leaving the store in a bad state, but that really shouldn't be happening. I'm using Persistent Stack, external 'library' to manage all of the CoreData (instead of AppDelegate) which is readable on https://gist.github.com/mluisbrown/7015953

CoreData Fetching from TodayView Extension:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

      self.persistentStack = [[PersistentStack alloc] initWithStoreURL:self.storeURL modelURL:self.modelURL];
        self.managedObjectContext = self.persistentStack.managedObjectContext;
}


- (NSURL*)storeURL
{
    //NSURL* documentsDirectory = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:YES error:NULL];
    // return [documentsDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"WhatIOwe.sqlite"];
    NSURL *directory = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"group.com.bittank.io"];
    NSURL *storeURL = [directory  URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"WhatIOwe.sqlite"];



    return  storeURL;

}

- (NSURL*)modelURL
{
    return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"WhatIOwe" withExtension:@"momd"];
}





- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    self.persistentStack = [[PersistentStack alloc] initWithStoreURL:self.storeURL modelURL:self.modelURL];

    self.managedObjectContext = self.persistentStack.managedObjectContext;


    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"OweInfo" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                              initWithKey:@"details.date" ascending:NO];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
    [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                        managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                   cacheName:@"Root"];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;


    return _fetchedResultsController;

}
```

As suggested, I've tried a merge policy in my persistent stack:

```
[self.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                                       configuration:nil
                                                                                 URL:self.storeURL
                                                                             options:@{ NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey : @"WhatIOwe",
                                                                                        NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : @YES,
                                                                                        NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @YES,
                                                                                        NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy : @YES}
                                                                               error:&error];
```

Another observation, on configuring my NSManagedObjectContext, passing:

```
  [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:self.storeURL options:nil error:&error]; allows the extension to read the store (but still throw the error I'm having), but passing


   [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:self.storeURL options:@{ NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey : @"iCloudStore",
                                                                                                     NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : @YES,
                                                                                                     NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @YES,
                                                                                                     } error:&error]; will result in the extension not reading any data whatsoever.
```

Side-note:  `psc` is passed as

```
__weak NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = self.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator;
    self.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

Answer (score 1):

What is happening here is that you have two different processes accessing the same Core Data store, each with it's own `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`.

One process has modified the store - most likely a delete. The other process has no way of knowing that this delete occurred, and already had an object in memory that pointed to the now deleted data. When that process tries to access that object it must go to the store to get the data ("firing a fault"), which no longer exists.

Core Data is not designed for this kind of use, and the capabilities of extensions are very different than applications. If your extension is able to write to the same data that the application can you may reconsider your approach and make the extension only able to read the data, and never hold the data in memory for long. This will at least mitigate the most common ways to run into these problems.

Comment: Well, this works out fine for me, I only want extension to read, not write. Do you have some documentation that might point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Replying to above answer and the question:
"Core Data is not designed for this kind of use"

It totally is. The assessment is correct: Something has likely been deleted in the actual app, and the extension is not aware. Fortunately CoreData provides a way to deal with this case. Check out the stalenessInterval property of NSManagedObjectContext. It defines how long your in memory cache is good for. If you're having problems because your in memory cache goes out of date from disk store change because an external process is changing them, simply set the staleness interval to 0 in your extension, and that will tell CoreData to always fetch new values from the store and ignore the in memory cache.

If you're holding a reference to an object in memory, and that object is deleted in the store, you still may have issues, so always check to make sure the object you are accessing has not been deleted.

There are a few other options if you want to get more detail. You could send notifications from your main app to your extension when things get saved to provide a manual trigger for reloading your data. You could also send specific object ids across that have been deleted or modified and use the refreshObject... method to manually refresh. Or check out mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:. You might be able to manually serialize the dictionary that expects and then send it across.

You could also have the parent app handle all database accesses and send results back via notifications. This might be unnecessary.

All of this requires a bit of work, but you're going to run into that with any
database system where the database is being accessed across multiple processes, and there is caching.

Comment: Colin, thanks for your excellent answer, I'll explore these options carefully. What I don't understand is the need to send notifications, when my view loads or appears, I refetch and I reset my NSManagedObjectContext. Unfortunately, CoreData as a whole is still a bit mystifying from my standpoint, so I might have this the wrong way around.

Comment: One other note, I've tried merging changes, but I have little to no idea how to  check if an object has been deleted from the store.

Comment: I've set the staleness, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues with your code which are likely leading to a confused Core Data state. I can't be certain that they're causing your problem, but at the moment things are messed up badly enough that trying to debug this specific error is getting ahead of things. These problems include:

- Confusion about how you're sharing data between your app and the extension.

  You can do this using iCloud, or you can do it by using an app group to share the persistent store directly. You appear to be attempting both, which is not just unnecessary but also likely to cause problems keeping the extension up to date.

  **If you use iCloud** to share data, you do not need the app group, because both the app and the extension will get their data from iCloud. You don't share a local persistent store in this case, instead the data is transferred via iCloud.

  **If you use an app group** to share the persistent store file, you have no need of iCloud. The app and the extension both access the same file, which is located in the group container. Each can both read and write it.
- Conflicting iCloud setups. You're using different values for `NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey` in different places. Even assuming that iCloud is working properly, this is going to prevent you from sharing data. If the app and extension are going to share via iCloud, they need to access the same cloud store, but you seem to be directing them to use separate cloud data stores.
- You're not actually using the merge policy you're aiming for. You're passing `NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy` as one of the options when adding the persistent store file, but this isn't actually a valid option there. I would have expected at least a console message about this, but if there isn't one then it means Core Data is just silently ignoring that key. You set a merge policy by setting the value of the `mergePolicy` attribute on your managed object context. With no merge policy, you're falling back on the default `NSErrorMergePolicy`.
- Unusual, suspicious code when adding the persistent store. In most cases with Core Data you'd add the persistent store and then later on create one or more managed object contexts. You appear to be creating the context first and only later adding a persistent store. That's not **necessarily** wrong but it's very unusual. If I were working on this code, it'd be a red flag to look over the life cycle of the Core Data stack very carefully. Especially if, as your code comments indicate, you're not getting any data at all in some cases.

Again I'm not sure if the above is directly causing this specific error, but they're going to be causing problems of various types and it wouldn't be surprising if the resulting confused state leads to this error.

Comment: So far, I've had little to no luck with iCloud, despite it working pre-iOS 8. I think, without the NSPersistentStoreCoordinator saving in the app group, it tries to fetch from iCloud, but since the parent app doesn't work at all with iCloud, it doesn't receive data.

Comment: Ok, so I've resolved issues 2 and 3, but iCloud is not being cooperative.

Comment: According to Apple, accessing Core Data iCloud functionality from an extension is not supported in iOS 8. https://devforums.apple.com/message/1050891#1050891

Comment: That's strange because Apple also provides a [demo app that uses iCloud in app extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Lister/Introduction/Intro.html).